# Categorical factors in normal linear model

Tags: categorical-data, linear-model

If I have two factors, $A$ with 2 levels, and $B$ with 3 levels, what should my base model be if I want to test if there is an interaction between the two factors?

Do I choose the interaction model (lm(x ~ A*B)) as my base, and then do an F-test for a sub-model (say, the one where we add the factors ((lm(x ~ A + B))), or do I choose a "bigger" model as my base, and then do an F-test with the interaction model being the sub-model?

If I did the latter, then I wouldn't know what to choose as the "bigger" base model. If I did the former, then I am not sure how I can reason that doing an F-test for the additive model really is the "next one" in line to test? I mean, maybe the F-test failing does not indicate that "there really is an interaction" but rather indicates "your new submodel is definitely not accurate".

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to review the latter model.  Using the `mtcars` data set as an example, with the following code:

```
 DF <- data.frame(mtcars)
 DF <- DF[,c(1, 2, 9)]
 fit <- lm(mpg ~ I(factor(am))*I(factor(cyl)), data = DF)
 summary(fit)
```

We get this result:

```
Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      22.900      1.751  13.081 6.06e-13 ***
I(factor(am))1                    5.175      2.053   2.521 0.018176 *  
I(factor(cyl))6                  -3.775      2.316  -1.630 0.115155    
I(factor(cyl))8                  -7.850      1.957  -4.011 0.000455 ***
I(factor(am))1:I(factor(cyl))6   -3.733      3.095  -1.206 0.238553    
I(factor(am))1:I(factor(cyl))8   -4.825      3.095  -1.559 0.131069    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.032 on 26 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7877,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7469 
F-statistic: 19.29 on 5 and 26 DF,  p-value: 5.179e-08
```

I think that the interpretation if this table is critical to understanding the interaction terms.  You can get a great explanation for interpretation of this table [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/interpreting-interaction-coefficient-in-r-part1-lm/). To answer your question, the F-test is performed for the entire model as seen in the last line of the results.  With that test being significant, we can consider the results of the multiple comparisons for each coefficient including the last two coefficients which are the interaction terms.  The interaction terms in this model do not have statistically significant P-values.  It's easy to see the effects of these interactions when this data is plotted and they are arguably close to significant.  In this case I believe that there is too little data in the data set to support significance testing for all of the coefficients in our model. All that being said, the `Y ~ A * B` model is going to give you results to show the significance of your interactions.

[image]